# Question about conditional convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let   $\sum_{k \in N}a_k$ be  a conditional convergent series such that  $\sum_{k \in N}a_k > 0$.

**Question** Is an inequality  $\sum_{k \in N}a_k \ln(k)>0$ valid?

P.S. Here we  assume that  $(a_k)$ is sequence of real numbers.

P.S. Here we assume  that  $\sum_{k \in N}a_k \ln(k)$  is convergent because in other hand  the question has no sense.

Comment: Consider $\sum \frac{ (-1)^n }{2^n} $ geometric series?

Comment: @Learner  This series is not conditionally convergent.

Comment: It's not valid.  Consider the series $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N} (-1)^{k+1}/\ln(k)$.  Then the series in question becomes $\sum(-1)^{k+1}$ which does not converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \ln(2) > 0$, but
I believe (and think I can prove) that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} < 0$.

But in any case, if you had an example where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n > 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \log n > 0$ (both series being conditionally convergent), try $b_n = -a_n$ for $n > 1$ while $b_1 > 0$.  Since $\log(1) = 0$, the value of $b_1$ does not affect $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \log n$, which is negative.  But for $b_1$ sufficiently large, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the Robert Israel's answer, note that $$\log\left(N\right)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2(N+1)}<\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}<\log\left(N\right)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2N}\tag{1}
 $$ which follows from the well known bounds for the [harmonic numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html), and so using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\log\left(k\right)}{k}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}\right)\log\left(N\right)-\int_{1}^{N}\frac{\sum_{k\leq t}\frac{1}{k}}{t}dt
 $$ hence, using $(1)$, we get $$\frac{\log^{2}\left(N\right)}{2}+\frac{\log\left(N\right)}{2\left(N+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\right)<S<\frac{\log^{2}\left(N\right)}{2}+\frac{\log\left(N\right)}{2N}+\frac{1}{2N}-\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}
 $$ so it is sufficient to note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}\log\left(k\right)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}\log\left(k\right)
 $$ $$=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2N}\frac{\log\left(k\right)}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\log\left(2k\right)}{k}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\log^{2}\left(2\right)}{2}-\gamma\log\left(2\right)}\approx-0.159869$$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$. Maybe it is interesting to note that it is value of $-\eta\left(1\right)$, where $\eta(s)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Derivatives).

Comment: @ Marco Cantarini   Thank you  very much for completion Robert Israel's  answer.

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia You're welcome.

Comment: @Cantarini  It will be  very good  if you generalise your approach for solution of the quastion at   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877655/can-we-predict-the-sign-of-the-derivative-of-the-series-by-its-values-at-points